# MVC 4 Bundling URL instead of files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

I think my title says everyting, I want to bundle a set of action urls which return JavaScriptResult instead of physical files, is this somehow possible?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you will have to wait for new release of ASP.NET MVC.
WebOptimization library is a separate project - that is developed somehow independently.

I am not 100% sure if this is something that you have been looking for but there is a support for virtual path providers now:

http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2012/10/20/new-web-optimization-pre-release-package-on-nuget/

Comment: THX for this info, but I don't find a tutorial who to do what I want, can you help me on this?

Only a simple example how to get js content from a controller action.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your scenario a bit more?  My guess is the answer is no, if what yare looking for is whether bundling will effectively drill down and fetch the contents of urls and then minify/bundle them.

We are planning on adding virtual path provider support in the next release which might enable this scenario as you would then be able to write a VPP that could serve up the JavaScriptResult to the bundling system.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, too bad that it is not possible in MVC 4, so I will wait for the next release.